# importing a node module create an error

Tags: node.js

I imported node module 'request' in app.js but as soon as my script read,

```
var request = require('request');
```

it creates an error like below. Anyone has an idea?

Error Message:

> [SECURITY] node-uuid: crypto not usable, falling back to insecure Math.random()

Comment: 안광섭, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

request depends on the library [`node-uuid`](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid). 'node-uuid' is used for generating random [UUID's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), also called GUID's.

To get truly random UUID's, node-uuid requires a cryptographically secure random source. Normally it will use `crypto.randomBytes` (in node) or `crypto.getRandomValues` (in the browser), but if that does not exist it will fall back to Math.Random. However, Math.random **cannot generate cryptographically secure random numbers** ([read here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651789/is-math-random-cryptographically-secure)).

Request uses UUID's for its OAuth nonces and multipart file uploads. If you use OAuth, not having secure random nonces may be a security concern.

The crypto module *should* be present in all node installations (to my knowledge), so it's likely that you are running this code in a web browser environment. You may be running in a web browser that doesn't support the crypto module quite yet, and therefore Math.random is really your only option. You can check the [can i use page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getrandomvalues) to see if your browser supports `getRandomValues`.

Comment: I'm getting this error in nodejs 4.3.2, ubuntu 16.04

Comment: so, how can we get rid of this error? Should I use app's "ignore warnings function?"