# Content Security Policy (csp) nonce: how long or complex should be a nonce

Tags: content-security-policy, nonce

I have a site which uses nonce. Everything works well. But how long or complex should be the nonce.

My little nonce maker is just this:

```
let generateNonce = (length = 32) => {
  const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let nonce = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    nonce += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
  return nonce;
};
```

A call of `generateNonce()` returns something like `hERnT30lr0G3Hw4b5eQCjuC423a3PcBl`.

32 characters of numbers, lower and upper case letters. Is this complex enough or even too long?

Comment: See the CSP spec section at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#security-nonces, which says nonce values *“should be at least 128 bits long (before encoding), & should be generated via a cryptographically secure random number generator”*. Your `hERnT30lr0G3Hw4b5eQCjuC423a3PcBl` has more than 128 bits, so that”s fine. But Math.random() isn’t cryptographically secure. See the explanations at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651854/441757 & https://security.stackexchange.com/q/181580/86150. Use Crypto.getRandomValues() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues instead.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you. Very informative and useful links. Could you post it as an answer please.

Comment: OK — added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the CSP spec section at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#security-nonces, which says:

> [nonce values] should be at least 128 bits long (before encoding), and should be generated via a cryptographically secure random number generator

The question’s `hERnT30lr0G3Hw4b5eQCjuC423a3PcBl` value is more than 128 bits, so that’s OK.

But `Math.random()` isn’t cryptographically secure; https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651854/441757 and https://security.stackexchange.com/q/181580/86150. Use [`Crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) instead.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @sideshowbarker the nonce generator could be like this (nodejs)

```
// require nodes native crypto module
const crypto = require('crypto');

// create 128 bit nonce synchronously
const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
```

`output = 1e31b6130c5be9ef4cbab7eb38df5491`

[crypto.randomBytes(size[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)

> Generates cryptographically strong pseudo-random data. The size argument is a number indicating the number of bytes to generate.