# Making random string of length n composed of solely 0's and 1's

Tags: javascript, string, random

What is a good ways to make random strings of length `n`, where the strings consist of only 0's and 1's?

- (obviously strings will repeat after some point, but assume we have enough length so we don't hit this ).

Would using `math.random()` and `round` and then just joining the generating numbers be good?

Maybe there is a way to generate all $n$ digits at once instead of in a loop as in above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods:

1. concat strings using a `for loop`

```js
function buildStrForLoop(n) {
   let str = ''
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      str += Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5)
   }
   return str
}
```

2. generate an array using `Array.from` and then `join`

```
function buildStrArrayFrom(n) {
   return Array.from({ length: n }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5)).join('')
}
```

Note i use `floor` and add 0.5 instead of using `round` as it was slightly faster.

I timed this on my M1 mac setting `n=10000000` and got ~1000ms for both methods.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `.toString(2)` to convert our random number to base 2 and get a bunch of 0's and 1's all at the same time (as opposed to only yielding one 0 or 1 with rounding), which greatly reduces the amount of times our loop has to execute. It also uses [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) to be cryptographically secure, but you could just as easily use `Math.random()` instead of `rando()` if you chose to.

```js
function get01String(length){
  var str = "";
  while(str.length < length) str += rando().toString(2).slice(2);
  return str.slice(-length);
}

console.log(get01String(5));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning rando.js and being cryptographically secure. I don't need that (for my application it doesn't matter if the number is predictable, so long as I am not getting multiple repeats), but its a worthwhile consideration in general.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that might do what you need:

`(Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999999 - 111111111)) + 111111111).toString(2)`

Truncate from the left to the length you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. I made a function, which creates a string with 0s and 1s.

Maybe there are better options, but it may help you.

```
function stringMaker(lenght) {
            let string = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
                string += Math.round(Math.random());
            }
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = string;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, *[and this is not cryptographically secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651789/is-math-random-cryptographically-secure)*:

```js
generateRandomStringOfLength = n => {
  let string = ''
  while (string.length < n) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      string = string.concat(1)
    } else string = string.concat(0)
  }
  return string;
}
```