# How important is it to use a "more random" RNG in a JavaScript RPG?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm building a relatively small Javascript Role Playing Game. As would be expected, it involves a lot of random number generation: damage rolls, to-hit rolls, ability success rolls, etc. At the moment, I'm using Javascript's native `Math.random()`, but from what I've heard, it's [not all that random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578700/how-trustworthy-is-javascripts-random-implementation-in-various-browsers) and [more random alternatives exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript).

Should I should bother using a non-native RNG/more obscure generation method, and if so, which one should I use?

Comment: That would totally depend on your application's requirements.  Does your application need a "more random than random" generator?  The key concept here is "cryptographically strong;" if you're not dealing in encryption, you may not need such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You Aren't Gonna Need It](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt)

If you're not sure you'll need a better RNG, then you probably don't need a better RNG. For your purposes, `Math.random` is more than good enough.

However, if you plan on calling `Math.random` in many different places, you might want to wrap the call in your own function. That way, if you decide you really do need a better RNG you can make the change in one location.

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping `Math.random()` in another function sounds like an excellent idea - I appreciate the advise!